# Logout my account on other computer

Tags: users

I was using a computer somewhere to login my site as admin, but forgot to logout. How can I logout my account from another computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just remove the relevant entries from the sessions table:

```
db_delete('sessions')->condition('uid', $your_user_id)->execute();
```

That should log the user out everywhere.

Comment: Thank You Clive. Can I use the phpmyadmin and delete all my "uid" rows under "sessions" section?

Comment: Just did that and work like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote up a [small drush command](https://drupal.org/node/1611952) to do this:

```
$ drush help session-delete
Delete user sessions from the database.
Examples:
 drush session-delete all                  Delete all sessions.
 drush session-delete 64                   Delete sessions for user id 64.
Aliases: sess-del
```

Technically, this just deletes the session and doesn't do a proper logout.  Those are nearly identical, though, under most circumstances.

This patch hasn't been committed, so you would need to download [drush extras](https://drupal.org/project/drush_extras) and apply it, or just extract the file from the patch and add it to your local commands.